# I'm supposed to use void function but i don't know how

Tags: java, function, void

```
public class LABEX01
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     print_header();
   }
   public static void print_header()
    {
      System.out.println("Name")
      Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in)
      double m = 3;
      double n = 0;
      System.out.print("type 12 and Press enter");
      n = kbd.nextDouble();
      double p = m * n;
      double q = 0;
      q = (double)Math.sqrt(p);
      System.out.printf("m = %f", m);
      System.out.printf("n = %f", n);
      System.out.printf("p = %f", p);
      System.out.printf("q = %f", q);
    }
}
```

I'm supposed to use a programmer defined function to print your name as the first line of your output. I tried using "print_header" but that doesn't seem to work.
I'm also supposed to use a programmer defined value returning function to assign value of "m * n" to integer variable "P".
I kinda having trouble understanding void functions, so if anyone can explain it to me in a Simple way, please help.

Comment: You're not flushing the output stream after the second print.  Also, what does "doesn't seem to work" mean?

Comment: _"doesn't seem to work"_ or not compiling? I saw missing semicolons , `;`

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question on void functions, a void function is simply a function that doesn't use the return keyword return a value. Returning from a void function simply ends the function.

This is NOT valid:

```
public void will_not_compile() {
 int value = 1;
 return value;
}
```

This is valid:

```
public void return_from_void(){
 int value = 1;
 return;
}
```

Comment: It is possible to return from a void function. `public void foo(){ return; }` is valid, the return just makes the function end. This is typically used to exit a function early rather than exiting at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The code :

```
System.out.println("Name")
Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in)
```

should be

```
System.out.println("Name");
Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
```

you missing semicolons.